# Passing const T& as this to a constexpr member function

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am trying to fix some library code where a boiled-down minimal version looks like this:

```
 #include <iostream>

 template <typename RangeT>                                          
 struct formatter {                               
     constexpr void format(const RangeT& values) {    
         for (auto it = values.begin(), end = values.end(); it != end; ++it) { 
             std::cout << it << "\n";                
         }                                                                       
     }                                    
 }; 

template <typename RangeT, typename Formatter> 
struct type_erased {                                                       
    static void format(const void* arg) {                                
        Formatter f;                   
        f.format(*static_cast<const RangeT*>(arg)); 
    }                                                  
};                                                                 

struct view {   
    int count_;                                

    constexpr View(int count) : count_(count) {}  

    constexpr int 
    begin() { return 0; }                   

    constexpr int                                                    
    end() { return -1; } 
};                      

int                                                         
main()                                                         
{                               
    View view(5);       
    void* ptr = static_cast<void*>(&view);                          
    type_erased<View, formatter<View>>::format(ptr); 
}
```

The above code does not compile in GCC since:

```
../src/view.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr void formatter<RangeT>::format(const RangeT&) [with RangeT = View]’:
../src/view.cpp:21:9:   required from ‘static void type_erased<RangeT, Formatter>::format(const void*) [with RangeT = View; Formatter = formatter<View>]’
../src/view.cpp:43:41:   required from here
../src/view.cpp:11:15: error: passing ‘const View’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   11 |     for (auto it = values.begin(), end = values.end(); it != end; ++it) {
  |               ^~
../src/view.cpp:31:5: note:   in call to ‘constexpr int View::begin()’
   31 |     begin() { return 0; }
  |     ^~~~~
../src/view.cpp:11:36: error: passing ‘const View’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   11 |     for (auto it = values.begin(), end = values.end(); it != end; ++it) {
  |                                    ^~~
../src/view.cpp:34:5: note:   in call to ‘constexpr int View::end()’
   34 |     end() { return -1; }
```

What are the rules regarding `this` in constexpr member function? Is it subject to the rules specified for function parameters or are there special constraints?

How would I go about fixing this error? If it would only be the formatter struct I would use `RangeT&&` and `std::move` since views are by definition copyable in O(1) as far as I know. I don't know how to do that with the type erasure step in the mix though...

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with constexpr as much as it is an issue with the use of begin() and end(). Use cbegin() and cend().

Comment: @RianQuinn Or `const auto it`

Comment: Using `const auto` yields the same result (i.e. the same error). And std::experimental::ranges::filter_view (which is the actual type here) has no cbegin/cend.

Comment: With GCC Trunk making both begin and end const functions gets it to compile. https://godbolt.org/z/3_wKh9

Comment: Indeed that compiles. In other words those functions cannot take const void* / const auto& parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with `constexpr`.

You have a reference to `const` `RangeT`, and you're trying to invoke non-`const` member functions on it (`begin()` and `end()`).

Provide `const` overloads (and/or `cbegin()`/`cend()` variants) if you want to permit that.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that ranges (or at least views) do not implement const variants - rendering this infeasible. However your answer still provides the explanation, so I mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: That's a shame :(

Answer (score 1):

In your code as begin and end are not const functions the `this` pointer can't point to a `const` object without  "discarding qualifiers".

By making the functions `const` then the `this` pointer can point to a `const` object.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

https://godbolt.org/z/3_wKh9